# PHP Check if all elements of one array are found in another

Tags: php, arrays

How can I compare the 2 arrays `$required` and `$found` to see if all elements of $required are present in $found? I don't care if there are more elements are in `$found`, as long as those of `$required` ones are.

I don't think giving a specific arrays example will make a difference but here they are:

```
$required = array (
    0 => 'this',
    1 => 'element',
    2 => 'is',
    3 => 'required'
);
$found = array (
    0 => 'this',
    1 => 'required',
    2 => 'be',
    3 => 'is',
    4 => 'extra',
    5 => 'element'
);
```

Will [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) do the trick even of there are more elements in `$found`? If yes, could you please provide an example? By reading the documentation I wasn't able to 100% understand how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does array\_intersect() do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927467/what-does-array-intersect-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the number of elements in the intersect are the same as are in `$required`. For example:

```
$required = array (
    0 => 'this',
    1 => 'element',
    2 => 'is',
    3 => 'required'
);
$found = array (
    0 => 'this',
    1 => 'required',
    2 => 'be',
    3 => 'is',
    4 => 'extra',
    5 => 'element'
);

var_dump(count(array_intersect($required, $found)) === count($required)); // true
var_dump(count(array_intersect($required, array('that'))) === count($required)); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I wouldn't of thought of using count.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. `array_intersect` will get you an intersection as described on the man page.

So, to achieve your goal, you would also have to check if the result of the `array_intersect` has the same ammount of elements as `$required` does.

I don't know of a function from stdlib that would do exactly this, however, on larger arrays I guesstimate you would probably be better of (performance wise) with custom function designed for this exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The arrays I'm comparing will only have 20-25 elements each so it shouldn't be too much of a performance overhead.